# Angular lazy load does not work when invoking forRoot

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a lazy load module which needs to expose providers, so I am using the `forRoot` convention and returning the following code:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild([
    {path: "", component: LazyComponent},
  ])],
  declarations: [LazyComponent],
})
export class LazyModule {
  static forRoot() {
    return {
      ngModule: LazyModule,
      providers: [provider]
    };
  }
}
```

The problem is when I invoke the forRoot in my app module the lazy load does not work anymore. ( I don't see the separate chunk in my console )

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HelloComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    LazyModule.forRoot() <======== this stops the lazy load module
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

From what I learned it should only make the providers singleton, why it does not work?

Comment: If you import LazyLoad module in eager module then webpack won't create chunk for it

Comment: So what you are saying is that I can't get lazy load my modules and use forRoot at the same time?

Comment: You can create separate module that contains only providers and import it

Answer (score 6):

As of right now, it's not possible to execute a `forRoot` (or any other configuration static method of this sort) in a module that will load lazily. The problem here is that such a method returns a `ModuleWithProviders` while loadChildren requires a `NgModuleFactory`.

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar issue where I had to lazy load a module with some configurations. So, I came up with this temporary fix.

> Lazy Module

```
    @NgModule({
          imports: [
             RouterModule.forChild([
              {path: "", component: LazyComponent},
             ])],
          declarations: [LazyComponent],
    })
    export class LazyModule {
       // considering the function only handle providers 
       static setDynamicProviders(provider?: any) {
            if(LazyModule && LazyModule.__annotations__ && LazyModule.__annotations__[0]){
            LazyModule.__annotations__[0].providers.push(provider);               
          }
            return LazyModule;
       }
   }
```

> Parent Module

```
const someService = {
  provide: 'SOME_TOKEN',
  useFactory: (dependecy1) => (//dome something with dependency1)
  deps: [SOME_DEPENDENCY_TOKEN]
}

@NgModule({
 imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([
        path: 'lazy',
        loadChildren: ()=>(import('*your path to lazy module*').then(ref => ref.LazyModule.setDynamicProvider(someService)))
    ])
  ]
})
```

So, I am just modifying the ***annotations*** created by `@NgModule` Decorator. At this stage, Angular does not support lazy loading with static methods that return `ModuleWithProviders`.

Comment: In case of 13th version you can push a provider as `LazyModule['ɵinj'].providers.push(provider)`

Answer (score 1):

When you import a `LazyModule` in your `AppModule` imports array it is not "lazy" anymore. A lazy module should only be referenced in a dedicated `RoutingModule`.

So if I understood you correctly you would like to share a Service between your LazyModules?

If so remove `LazyModule` from `AppModule`  and create a SharedModule and move your Service you like to share inside the `providers` array in SharedModule. Import SharedModule in your `AppModule` with `forRoot` and import your `SharedModule` without `forRoot` in your LazyModules

Answer (score 0):

Try below code when we define a module is Lazy RouterModule.forChild:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild([
    {path: "", component: LazyComponent},
  ])],
  declarations: [LazyComponent],
})
export class LazyModule { }
```

But when we load in the parent module, try the below code:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HelloComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
     {
         path: '',
         loadChildren: './layout/layout.module#LayoutModule',
         canActivate: [AuthGuard]
     }
    ]) <======== right way to load lazy module
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Note: FullPath is like './moduleFolder/lazy.module#LayoutModule'

## LayoutModule is your exported Module Name

Please let me know

Comment: This doesn't answer his question. Where is forRoot mentioned here?

Answer (score 0):

If a module (let's call it `LazyModule`) requires some parameters to be provided through `forRoot` and is imported inside two separate apps (let's call them A and B), we can define two modules (one in each app)

In app A:

```
@NgModule({
imports: [
    LazyModule.forRoot(aParamFromAppA)
]
})
export class AModule
```

And in app B :

```
@NgModule({
imports: [
    LazyModule.forRoot(anotherParamFromAppB)
]
})
export class BModule
```

It allows us to import both those modules lazily from their app :

```
loadChildren: () => import('PATH/TO/MODULE/A/AModule.module').then(m => m.AModule)
loadChildren: () => import('PATH/TO/MODULE/B/BModule.module').then(m => m.BModule)
```