# Lazy Module with forRoot method

Tags: javascript, angular, lazy-loading, angular-routing, angular8

I have an angular module loaded lazy using the new angular 8 method:

```
loadChildren: () => import('path').then(module => module.MyModuleClass)
```

This works fine, but now I require to configure the module. Normally this is easily achieved by implementing a static `forRoot()` method that returns a `ModuleWithProviders` object. But if I call it like this:

```
loadChildren: () => import('path').then(module => module.MyModuleClass.forRoot(myConfig))
```

... then I get a runtime error `Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No NgModule metadata found for '[object Object]'.`

Is there a way to use a module configuration for lazy loaded modules?

Comment: a service might be an alternative for you to pass attributes to the lazy loaded class

Comment: Sadly it is a requirement for the lazy module to work independent of the main application, because it should be possible to load it into different applications.

Comment: you can always have a central configurations service that both your main app and this other module share, but I will keep a tab on this question. Someone else might give us an alternative

Comment: this was someone else's answer for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48602054/4604645
so it seems we cannot use forRoot on lazy loading